# Is there a way to do an SVN switch command with MSBuild Community Tasks?

Tags: svn, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

Does anyone know how to issue an svn "switch" command with the Msbuild.Community.Tasks.Subversion toolset?  I want to switch my working copy from trunk to tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I use **SvnClient** command for that

Here the example how it can be done in msbuild file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ExtSrcRoot>...here the path to destination folder...</ExtSrcRoot>
  <GMOCK_REPO>http://googlemock.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release-1.6.0</GMOCK_REPO>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
   <DEP_GMOCK Include="$(ExtSrcRoot)/gmock"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="dep_gmock_up" Condition="Exists(@(DEP_GMOCK))">
  <SvnClient Command="switch " RepositoryPath="$(GMOCK_REPO)" LocalPath="@(DEP_GMOCK)"/>
  <SvnUpdate LocalPath="@(DEP_GMOCK)"/>
</Target>
```

GMOCK_REPO can be changed to any tag your want.

Comment: @end-user don't forget accept answer if it will solve your question :)